# Multiple inputs leading to iframe javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Is it possible to use multiple inputs, leading to the same iframe, but I need each input will show different content in the iframe, mainly like embedding things(such as youtube). Mainly, it's to switch between videos/songs, that would be my intention at least.

HTML:

```
<div align="left">
    <a><input id="mp3" title="YoutubeTitleOne" type="image" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/(video1)" src="dot" alt="Submit" onclick="load()" height="21"></a>
    <a><input id="mp3" title="YoutubeTitleTwo" type="image" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/(video2)" src="dot" alt="Submit" onclick="load()" height="21"></a>
</div>
<div id="mp3" style="height:350px;width:574px;background-color:#000000" align=
"center">
    <div><iframe id="play" src width="98.60%" height="310px" style="border:0px" align="center"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function load() {
            document.getElementById("play").src = document.getElementById("mp3").value;
        }
```

Comment: At first, `id`s must be unique within the document. Then, why to use `input type=image`, wouldn't just `img` be a better choice to put to `a`?.

Comment: just remove the id for the input, and modify the onclick to onclick="load(this.value)", update the load function to load(url){...src=url;}